# Visual Studio 2015 git integration and interactive revert

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and git for source control.

With Visual Studio 2013, 2012 and 2010 there was a really useful feature in the integration plugin: a light blue (LightSkyBlue) bar on the left side of the code window that highlighted the code changes since the last commit.
It was similar to the yellow bar that highlights the edited lines before save and the green line for the modified and saved lines.

Clicking on that bar, the old IDE opens a live preview of the last commited code and let you revert that single portion of code to the original.

Now in Visual Studio 2015 this feature is no more present.

Does anyone know if is there a way to enable it, or has it been removed from the integration plugin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found that, in visual studio 2010, there was an option in Git Source Control Provider named "disable the diff margin". This option disables and enables the function I was looking for.

In VS2015 this option is no more present, so I found an extension named "Git Diff Margin" that does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a Visual Studio Enterprise Feature, but whenever I'm doing changes in my code, I can see those changes above every single function, click on the "Changes" or "Last modified" gray text, gives me exactly the funcitons you're describing. It's not as "in your face" as the previous versions of VS like you describe, but I find it less distractive.

[image]

Comment: @pedro-g-dias it is not the same function: "changes" gives you the history of the commits made into git. I am looking for the old function that compares the current modified (but not yet committed) code portion with the last committed one

Comment: Right-click, "Compare with previous"?

Comment: @pedro-g-dias: ok, I found that, in visual studio 2010, there was an option in Git Source Control Provider named "disable the diff margin". This option disables and enables the function I was looking for. Then I found that for VS2015 there is an extension named "Git Diff Margin" that does exactly what I want. I invite you to try it, I find it very useful. Thanks for your time!